# Recover informations from CSV files with my awk script

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have this CSV files :

```
Monday,linux,6,0.2
Tuesday,linux,0.25,0.2
Wednesday,linux,64,3
```

I create a little script that allow me to recover the informations from my csv 
and to place them like this :

```
Day : Monday
OS : Linux
RAM : 6
CPU1 : 0.2
```

My script is :

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'[ ,;|.]' 'FNR==0{next}
               FNR>1 {
                        print "DAY : " $1;
                        print "OS :\n " $2
                        print "RAM :\n " $3
                        print "CPU1 :\n " $4
                     }' mycsvfile.csv
```

But the result is :

```
DAY : Tuesday
OS :
 linux
RAM :
 0
CPU1 :
 25
DAY : Wednesday
OS :
 linux
RAM :
 64
CPU1
```

Or I want :

```
DAY : Monday
OS : linux
RAM : 0.2
CPU 1 : 1

DAY : Tuesday
OS : linux
RAM : 0.25
CPU 1 : 0.2

DAY : Wednesday
OS : linux
RAM : 64
CPU 1 : 3
```

Can you tell me why my script doesn't works and why floats are not taken into account ?

Thank you !

Comment: You have `.` as a field separator. Use `-F'[ ,]'` or `-F'[[:space:],]'` instead of `-F'[ ,;|.]'`

Comment: wrt `FNR==0{next}` - given that `FNR` is the line number in the file currently being read, when do you expect `FNR==0` to be true? wrt `FNR>1 {` - why are you skipping the first line of your CSV? Is there actually a header line present in your real data that you haven't shown in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added tab and newline to same awk as Cyrus posted.

```
awk -F ',' '{
    print "DAY :",$1
    print "OS :",$2
    print "RAM :",$3
    print "CPU1 :",$4"\n"
}' OFS='\t' file

DAY :   Monday
OS :    linux
RAM :   6
CPU1 :  0.2

DAY :   Tuesday
OS :    linux
RAM :   0.25
CPU1 :  0.2

DAY :   Wednesday
OS :    linux
RAM :   64
CPU1 :  3
```

---

A more generic solution:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {split("DAY OS RAM CPU", header, " ")}{for (i=1;i<=4;i++) print header[i]":\t",$i;print ""}' t
DAY:     Monday
OS:      linux
RAM:     6
CPU:     0.2

DAY:     Tuesday
OS:      linux
RAM:     0.25
CPU:     0.2

DAY:     Wednesday
OS:      linux
RAM:     64
CPU:     3
```

More readable:

```
awk -F, '
    BEGIN {split("DAY OS RAM CPU", header, " ")}
    {
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
        print header[i]":\t",$i;
    print ""
    }' file
```